# cmd.exe at \\computername to run on remote machine

Tags: windows-xp, cmd.exe, privileges, windows-task-scheduler, nircmd

My original problem was the `NirCmd remote \\PC_D ...`  (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) was failing. I tracked that down to it using `at \\computername` command which is not working on all machines. The local use of `at time ...` works fine on all machines. I have three PCs (let's call them PC_L,PC_D,PC_H) and two of them are getting this error from testing in `cmd.exe`:

```
> at \\computername
> Access is denied
```

That shows `\\PC_L` is setup correctly but the other two are lacking something.
Something with `\\PC_H`  and `\\PC_D` is not setup properly (running XP SP3 home and XP PRO edition respectively).  Testing `shutdown` in `cmd.exe`:

```
> shutdown -s -m \\pc_h -t 9999
> The network path was not found.
```

This error seems puzzling. So to summarize:

```
FROM    FROM  TO    AT      REMOTE SHUT
TYPE    HOST  HOST  CMD     CMD
======  ====  ====  ======= ===========
XPPRO   PC_L  PC_D  FAILS   OK  
XPPRO   PC_L  PC_H  FAILS   FAILS
XPPRO   PC_D  PC_L  OK      OK
XPPRO   PC_D  PC_H  FAILS   FAILS
XPHOME  PC_H  PC_L  OK      OK   
XPHOME  PC_H  PC_D  FAILS   OK
```

I have checked the following:

- All machines are logged in with a the same user name with same password, and members of the Adminstrators group.
- Access file shares works fine.
- `net view \\computername` works.
- All machines are in same Workgroup name.

What other settings should I check?
(The two XPPRO machines should not have "FAIL" in above table, so that would be a good place to start. Once that's fix then look further at the "XPHOME" PC)

Comment: Thought about this and didn't come to a quick idea. So, while file share acces works, what's with nslookup, what are the routing tables saying? IP configuration?

Comment: @Clijsters nothing unusual these PC are on same subnet, have same routing info. nslookup with what arguments ?

Comment: See [nslookup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490721.aspx). `nslookup pcname` should help discovering DNS issues.